# Is it possible to pass an image file from one HTML page to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried it using many examples, but nothing seems to work using only HTML and Javascript/jQuery. Here's what I've tried so far:

The code of the page where I upload the page:

```html
    <form name="formSale" action="dress-preview.html" method="get">
        <div class="form-group upload third file-wrapper">
         <label for="uploadDress">Upload image:</label>
      <div class="file-upload">
       <span>Choose an image</span>
       <input type="file" name="uploadDress" id="uploadFile" required>
      </div>
       </div>
 </form>
```

The code of the page that will recieve the file:

```html
    <div class="image-preview">
  <div class="image">
   <img id="myImg" src="#" alt="">
   <div class="file-upload">
    <span>Elige una foto</span>
    <input type="file" name="uploadDress" id="uploadFile" required>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is te Javascript of the page that recieves the file

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    var url = document.location.href, params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'), data = {}, tmp, tmp1 = [];

    for(var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++){
       var j = i + 1;
       tmp = params[i].split("=");
       tmp1.push(tmp);
       data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }

   img_load(tmp1[0][1]);
}

function img_load(img){
    $(":file").change(function(){
        console.log(true);
        if(this.files && this.files[0]){
            console.log(true);
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = imageIsLoaded;
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
        }
    });
}

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
   $('#myImg').attr('src', e.target.result);
};
```

Is there any way I can use **Javascript/jQuery** to pass an image from
one **HTML** page to another? Or it's something that I can only do on
a server way (aka **PHP**)

Another thing I would like to mention is that, in the second HTML page, the div that contains the image preview is not inside a form.

Comment: Are both pages open at the same time? Or do you *move* from one to the other?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I move from one to the other

Comment: You could convert the image to base64, store it in localStorage and load the stored image on the second page.

Comment: @JamieO'Hanlon Can I convert it to base64 via a Javascript/jQuery method/function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Hesitated to make it part of a comment only, but...</sup>

**Don't store a binary file in localStorage.** (and even less in a cookie...) It is not meant for this.  localStorage is rather slow, and all synchronous. It also has a very limited storage capacity.

Instead, use [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API), which offers a far more performant API (although far more complicated to use), and which can store binary files directly.

Using [Mozilla's localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) library, it becomes as easy as:

```
function store() {
  localforage.setItem('myfile', f.files[0])
    .then(onfilesaved);
}

function getFile() {
  localforage.getItem('myfile')
    .then(useTheFile);
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fqo21sg5/1) demonstrating this since StackSnippet doesn't allow access to localStorage nor IndexedDB.

Note that IndexedDB offers the same protections as localStorage in terms of cross-origin requests.

Comment: I like it. May have to add `localForage` to my usual toolkit.

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you! How can I get it to display the image in the HTML that recieves the file?

Comment: @CodeXtack `function useTheFile(file) { yourImgElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(file); }`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're moving from one page to the other, we can't do it the way I would prefer (web messaging).

You're using `readAsDataURL`, which gies you a string, so you can store that in `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`:

```
// In `imageIsLoaded`
localStorage.theImage = e.target.result;
```

...and then in the other page load it:

```
someImage.src = localStorage.theImage;
```

Note that both web storage and data URLs have size limits, but if you're not dealing with gigabyte-size images, it should be fine. (IE8 limited data URLs to 32k, but IE8 doesn't support the File API that you're using to read the image, so...).

---

See [Kaiido's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50269494/157247) about optionally using IndexedDB if available (falling back to local storage if not) via the localForage library.

Answer (score 0):

You can store image in `cookie` or `localStorage` ;

You can store in cookie in following ways.

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    var url = document.location.href, params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'), data = {}, tmp, tmp1 = [];

    for(var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++){
       var j = i + 1;
       tmp = params[i].split("=");
       tmp1.push(tmp);
       data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }

   img_load(tmp1[0][1]);
}

function img_load(img){
    $(":file").change(function(){
        console.log(true);
        if(this.files && this.files[0]){
            console.log(true);
            $.cookie("image", this.files[0]);
        }
    });
}

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
   $('#myImg').attr('src', $.cookie("image"));
};
```

And `localStorage` in following ways.

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    var url = document.location.href, params = url.split('?')[1].split('&'), data = {}, tmp, tmp1 = [];

    for(var i = 0, l = params.length; i < l; i++){
       var j = i + 1;
       tmp = params[i].split("=");
       tmp1.push(tmp);
       data[tmp[0]] = tmp[1];
    }

   img_load(tmp1[0][1]);
}

function img_load(img){
    $(":file").change(function(){
        console.log(true);
        if(this.files && this.files[0]){
            console.log(true);
            // Store
localStorage.setItem("image", this.files[0]);
        }
    });
}

function imageIsLoaded(e) {
   $('#myImg').attr('src', localStorage.getItem("image"));
};
```

Comment: @R.García jquery is required.

Comment: @5740382 - Then add it, or use code blocks. Code *snippets* are for code you can run with the "Run code snippet" button.

Comment: *"You can store image in cookie or localStorage"* Storing it in a cookie would be an **amazingly** bad idea.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for suggestions. I have changed it to code blocks.